# publish the Views in dot net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my app, after `dotnet run` I was able to see the view called by:

```
return View("~/Views/v1.cshtml");
```

and I got the `Views` folder copied in the `publish` folder after adding in my `project.json` the below:

```
"publishOptions": {
     "include": ["Views"]
}
```

but after publishing the app, using the:

```
dotnet publish --output "publish" --configuration release
```

and running the:

```
e:\myApp\publish\dotnet myApp.dll
```

The view had not been displayed in the browser after being called by the controller.

what is the mistake i'm doing here, and how to get it fixed? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using non-convention patch to `Views` don't use project relative patch (like `~/` or `./`). So proper will be

> return View("Views/v1.cshtml");

Comment: I do not have a "wwwroot" folder in my app. I guess the mistake is in `return View("~/Views/v1.cshtml")` but do not know what exactly is

Comment: So first  answer for a important question: Do you have folder `Views` in your publish folder?

Comment: Convention is naming folder in `Views` by the same name of controller and then in `return View();` pass by parameter just name of view if its different than name of action. I see you dont use that convention

Comment: You are correct, I'm not using convention, but it is working fine when I use it `dotnet run`

Comment: Cuz `dotnet run` can use project relative patch. Try to set relative (not project relative with `~/`) patch what will be the same in project and after publish

Comment: using the absolute path `return View("E:/myApp/Views/v1.cshtml");` had not changed anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130126/discussion-between-hasan-a-yousef-and-j-doe).